# How to GROUP by MAX in sql?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Race

| RaceID | Year |
| --- | --- |
| 01 | 2010 |
| 02 | 2011 |
| 03 | 2011 |
| 04 | 2011 |
| 05 | 2012 |
| 06 | 2012 |
| 07 | 2013 |

Results

| ResultID | RaceID | Speed |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 01 | 180 |
| B | 02 | 190.5 |
| C | 03 | 185 |
| D | 04 | 170 |
| E | 05 | 200 |
| F | 06 | 190 |
| G | 07 | 220 |

How can i get the MAX speed of each year and GROup it by year??

Comment: Please show your current code and describe what is wrong with it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

So you join race and results on the common field i.e. race_id and then pick only year and speed after which you group by year and get max of speed.

```
SELECT 
  race.year
, MAX(results.speed) AS max_speed
FROM race 
JOIN results ON (race.raceid = results.raceid)
GROUP BY 
  race.year
```

Answer (score 1):

For 'Year' with 'max_Speed', 'recordist RaceID', 'ResultID':

```
select a.Year, a.max_Speed, b.RaceID, b.ResultID from
(select Year, max(Speed) max_Speed from Race a1 
 left join Results a2 on a2.RaceID = a1.RaceID
 group by Year
) a
left join
(select Year, Speed, b1.RaceID, ResultID from Race b1 
 left join Results b2 on b2.RaceID = b1.RaceID) b
 on b.Year = a.Year
and b.Speed = a.max_Speed
order by Year desc
```

For 'year' with 'max_speed' only:

```
select
    year
    , max(speed) max_speed
from race a
left join results b
    on b.raceID = a.raceID
group by year
order by year desc
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/50324c/24)